# How do I add rows with node-csv?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I know I can modify rows using the following code:

```
const data = fs.createReadStream('api.csv')
  .pipe(csv.parse({columns: true}))
  .pipe(csv.transform(record => {
    // can modify row here
    return record;
  }));
  .pipe(csv.stringify({header: true}))
  .pipe(process.stdout);
```

But how do I add new rows? I think I have to write data to the pipeline, probably before `csv.stringify`, but I am not sure how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data to be added depends on the input data, as you indicated in your original question, you can call the transform with a callback function. For example, the following will duplicate each record.

```js
const data = fs.createReadStream('api.csv')
  .pipe(csv.parse({columns: true}))
  .pipe((data, callback) => setImmediate(() => callback(null, data, data))))
  .pipe(csv.stringify({header: true}))
  .pipe(process.stdout);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can write to the stream returned by the `pipe` method between the `transform` and `stringify`.

```
const data = fs.createReadStream('api.csv')
  .pipe(csv.parse({columns: true}))
  .pipe(csv.transform(record => {
    // can modify row here
    return record;
  }));

// Can add rows here
data.write({
  col1: 1,
  col2: 2
});

data.pipe(csv.stringify({header: true})).pipe(process.stdout);
```